# Подсчет кол-во пользователей зарегистрированных по дням за некоторый промежуток

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте! Хочу посчитать количество зарегистрированных пользователей за каждый день (например: 2017-06-01 зарегистрировано- 3 пользователя). Есть такой код:

```
$before = '2017-06-01';
$after = '2017-07-07';

$regTime = '';

$calcUserOfDay = 0;
$old = 0;
$new = 0;

$p = $db->query("SELECT `reg_date` FROM `users`");

while ($str = $p->fetch_assoc()) {

  $regTime = date("Y-m-d", $str['reg_date']) . '<br>';

  if($regTime > $before && $regTime <= $after)
  {
     if($old == 0)
     {
         $old = $regTime;
     }
     $new = $regTime;

     echo '<br>';
     echo  $old. ' vs ' . $new;

     if($new == $old)
     {
         $calcUserOfDay = $calcUserOfDay+1;
     }
     else
     {
         echo $calcUserOfDay .'<br>';
         $old = $new;
         $calcUserOfDay = 1;
     }
   }
}
```

Получаю результат:

```
2017-06-03 vs 2017-06-03

2017-06-03 vs 2017-07-03   1

2017-07-03 vs 2017-07-03

2017-07-03 vs 2017-07-03

2017-07-03 vs 2017-07-05   3

2017-07-05 vs 2017-07-06   1

2017-07-06 vs 2017-07-06
```

Последние два элемента сравниваются, но их результат НЕ ВЫВОДИТСЯ

Comment: `SELECT reg_date, count(1) FROM users where reg_date between '2017-06-01' and '2017-07-07' group by date(reg_date)`

Comment: `Последние два элемента сравниваются, но их результат НЕ ВЫВОДИТСЯ` - как ты это определил? Ты пользовался отладчиком и он показал, что есть два последних каких-то элемента и они сравниваются? Или это просто ты так считаешь?

Comment: @Mike, можете объяснить примерно как это работает?

Comment: ну  where фильтрует то что нам надо, group by собирает группирует до дня, count(1) считает записи

Comment: @ Алексей Шиманский, на сколько я понял, не сравниваются( Как это можно исправить?

Comment: @ Алексей Шиманский, и в моем случае кол-во зарегистрированных пользователей выводится только если `$old != $new`, а у двух последних записей значения одинаковы, то значение не получить

Comment: Такие вещи обычно делаются на уровне SQL-запроса, а не в коде. Смотрите ответ Mike'а - он дело написал

Comment: @Mike, извиняюсь за наглость, а как можно это вывести, получить значение?)

Comment: точно так же как вы сейчас из таблицы поле читаете. можно написать `... count(1) as cnt` что бы к нему $str['cnt'] обращаться

Comment: @Mike, а это он считает общее кол-во зарегистрированных пользователей? Мне нужно вывести статистику каждого дня

Comment: ну вы сделайте `print_r()` результата и посмотрите что у вас в массиве будет. набор там пар `$str['reg_date'], $str['cnt']`

Comment: @teran,` $str['reg_date']` в цикле выдает один единственный результат `148367454520`(время перевел в unix формат в запросе тоже), `$str['cnt']` выдает общее кол-во зарегистрированных за это время т.е. `20`

Comment: `select date(reg_date) as d` -> `$str['d']`

Comment: @teran, `SELECT date(reg_date) as d, count(1) as cnt FROM users where reg_date between '1483674545' and '1499374800' group by date(reg_date)`. Я все правильно сделал?